# Как сделать капчу для телеграмм бота?

Tags: python, telebot, captcha

Нужно, чтобы при команде старт, прежде всех функций пользователь прошел капчу. Как это реализовать в пайтоне?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте библиотеку **[pyTelegramBotCAPTCHA](https://github.com/SwissCorePy/pyTelegramBotCAPTCHA)**. На странице проекта достаточно подробно описаны примеры внедрения капчи.

Comment: там он используется для чат - бота, а не для обычного.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, какой обычный бот вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: я имею виду, бота которого нет в чате

Comment: @IllIDanStormRage там есть метод `captcha_manager.send_new_captcha` который вам и нужен

Answer (score 0):

А лучше самому сделать используя вот это

```
from captcha.image import ImageCaptcha
```